# React function not working on first call, but works every other time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, render

I'm sure it's a very simple problem but I've tried so many different things and I just make it worse. I'm building a nutrition app that has total calories. It's supposed to calculate total calories based on calories from api call and it works great after the second time. But the first time it shows 0

Nutrition Component

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [foodId, setFoodId] = useState("");
  const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([]);
  const [totalCal, setTotalCal] = useState(0);

  const addCal = (cal, totalCal) => {
    const total = cal + totalCal;
    setTotalCal(total);
  };

  // Getting user input for an argument to be used later in API call
  const getInput = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  // Submitting user input / starting API call / setting food to be searched
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsLoaded(true);
    // console.log(list);
  };

  // Function that holds API call using form input
  const getNutrition = food => {
    const appId = "e124e5bc";
    const appKey = "fd3e0319818416b4e8496e3502bcb565";
    fetch(
      `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/${food}?&appId=${appId}&appKey=${appKey}`
    )
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        let foodId = responseData.hits[0].fields.item_id;
        fetch(
          `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=${foodId}&appId=${appId}&appKey=${appKey}`
        )
          .then(response => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(responseData => {
            setFoodId(foodId);
            const foodObject = {
              calories: responseData.nf_calories,
              protein: responseData.nf_protein,
              food: responseData.item_name,
              key: foodId,
              totalCal: totalCal
            };
            addCal(foodObject.calories, totalCal);
            setFoodList([...foodList, foodObject]);
            setIsLoaded(false);
          });
      });
    console.log(isLoaded);
  };

  // Calling nutrition function that holds API
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) {
      getNutrition(search);
      setFoodId(foodId);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [isLoaded]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.nutritionContainer}>
      <FoodForm submit={handleSubmit} input={getInput} />
      <table className={styles.center}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Food Item</th>
            <th>Calories</th>
            <th>Protein</th>
            <th>Total Calories</th>
            <th>Total Protein</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <TableList foodList={foodList} />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nutrition;
```

List with dynamic table data from api call in Nutrition Component

```
const TableList = ({ foodList }) => {
  return foodList.map(item => (
    <tr key={item.key}>
      <td>{item.food}</td>
      <td>{item.calories}</td>
      <td>{item.protein}</td>
      <td>{item.totalCal}</td>
    </tr>
  ));
};

export default TableList;
```

Comment: Put search and foodId in your useEffect dependencies array

Comment: I tried that, it didn't help unfortunately

Comment: It will help prevent other bugs you would have seen

Comment: oh, understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code has a little problems with reusing same variable name again and check following code I fixed. When you use isLoaded value to default, Add search value to something as default.

I hope it will be helped. But for now, you api limit is over because i tested its alot. :P

**FIX 1**

```
useEffect(() => {
if (isLoaded) {
  getNutrition(search);
}}, [isLoaded]);
```

**FIX 2**

```
const getNutrition (food)=> {
 const appId = "e124e5bc";
 const appKey = "fd3e0319818416b4e8496e3502bcb565";
 fetch(
  `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/${food}?&appId=${appId}&appKey=${appKey}`
 )
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(responseData => {
    let fId = responseData.hits[0].fields.item_id;
    setFoodId(fId);

    fetch(
      `https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/item?id=${fId}&appId=${appId}&appKey=${appKey}`
    )
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        console.log("DATA", responseData);
        const foodObject = {
          calories: responseData.nf_calories,
          protein: responseData.nf_protein,
          food: responseData.item_name,
          key: foodId,
          totalCal: totalCal
        };
        addCal(foodObject.calories);
        setFoodList([...foodList, foodObject]);
        setIsLoaded(false);
      });
  });
console.log(isLoaded);};
```

**FIX 3**

```
const addCal = cal => {
const total = cal + totalCal;
setTotalCal(total);};
```

Comment: That's why it's taking me so long. It only gives you 50 calls lol. I'll check on these tomorrow & let you know. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Alright It was a mix of things & I got rid of useEffect, but I selected your answer as the accepted one because I implemented all of your fixes & moved some stuff around with the foodObject, add function and totalCal & it works! Thank you & everyone for your help & knowledge. I was able to implement the same one for protein as well

Answer (score 0):

because `isLoaded` is set initially to false and therefore it will not call `getNutrition(search); setFoodId(foodId);` inside `useEffect`

Comment: Tried setting is loaded to true initially, still behaved the same unfortunately.

Comment: Am I right that you set default search input value? If yes the default state input is set to "". Also check the network tab for first two calls. Are there correct?

Comment: Search input value comes from an input tag in another component called foodForm. But handleSubmit & handleInput are the only 2 functions being sent to that component so you can see them above

Comment: and first 2 calls are correct. All the information come sback and is displayed just fine, I just cant' get the addCal function to update properly. It works, just not at first.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain why your first api call isn't working but I have a few suggestions that night help.

First off I wouldn't use the useEffect hook at all. It unnecessarily complicates your code. You only need to call the api each time the form is submitted so why not just do it then? Instead of changing the is loaded value etc. You might find after doing that your error is gone, or at least it will be easier to understand what's happening in your code.

The other thing I would do is remove totalCals from state. Instead i would calculate it each time, unless you have thousands or hundreds of thounds of items it's really not going to be a performance issue. The benefits of this is that  your code will be easier to understand and if you said the issue was with the calories not updating this should fix it. It also means your state isn't denormalised. If you calculate it every time and then remove an item from the array, you dont need to worry about forgetting to also reduce the total etc.

Good luck!!

Comment: Nice! I'll have to try it tomorrow because the free API gets called at 50 calls but I will let you know results! So I was thinking that you had to use useEffect or componentDidMount on every API so its asynchronous but I can fix that! Thank you for looking into it!